# SSIS Script howto append text to end of each row in flat file?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I currently have a flat file with around 1million rows.
I need to add a text string to the end of each row in the file.

I've been trying to adapt the following code but not having any success :-

```
public void Main()
{
    // TODO: Add your code here

    var lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\SSISSource\Source\Source.txt");
    foreach (string item in lines)
    {
        var str = item.Replace("\n", "~20221214\n");
        var subitems = str.Split('\n');
        foreach (var subitem in subitems)
        {
            // write the data back to the file

        }
    }
    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

I can't seem to get the code to recognise the carriage return "\n" & am not sure howto write the row back to the file to replace the existing rather than add a new row. Or is the above code sending me down a rabbit hole & there is an easier method ??

Many thanks for any pointers &/or assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read your code as

> For each line in the file, replace the existing newline character with ~20221214 newline

At that point, the value of `str` is what you need, just write that! Instead, you split based on the new line which gets you an array of values which *could* be fine but why do the extra operations?

```
string origFile = @"E:\SSISSource\Source\Sourcetxt";
string fixedFile = @"E:\SSISSource\Source\Source.fixed.txt";

// Make a blank file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fixedFile, "");

var lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\SSISSource\Source\Source.txt");
foreach (string item in lines)
{
    var str = item.Replace("\n", "~20221214\n");
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fixedFile, str);
}
```

Something like this ought to be what you're looking for.

Comment: I think the read all lines is getting rid of the \n in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Read all lines is likely getting rid of the \n in each record. So your replace won't work.

Simply append your string and use @billinKC's solution otherwise.

BONUS:

I think `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");` is what you are trying to append to each line

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @billinKC & @KeithL

KeithL you were correct in that the \n was stripped off. So I used a slightly amended version of @billinKC's code to get what I wanted :-

```
string origFile = @"E:\SSISSource\Source\Sourcetxt";
string fixedFile = @"E:\SSISSource\Source\Source.fixed.txt";

// Make a blank file
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fixedFile, "");

var lines =  System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\SSISSource\Source\Source.txt");
foreach (string item in lines)
{
    var str = item + "~20221214\n";
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fixedFile, str);
}
```

As an aside KeithL - thanks for the DateTime code however the text that I am appending is obtained from a header row in the source file which is being read into a variable in an earlier step.